# NFCTagReaderSession property returns false instead of true: Xamarin.iOS Development using NFC

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, nfc, core-nfc

I'm having issues regarding the NFC on iOS 17.1.2. I have an iOS Application that uses the class NFCReading and I'm trying to create a session that reads ISO15693 tags, so I'm using the NFCTagReaderSession from CoreNFC.
The problem is when I'm trying to read using the NFC, it says that the _session.Ready property of the session is false, while I expect that value to be true.

```
public MobileNfcReader(AppDelegate appDelegate)
    {
        _appDelegate = appDelegate;
        _session = new NFCTagReaderSession(NFCPollingOption.Iso15693
            , this, null);
        sessionQueue = new Queue<NFCReaderSession>();
        dispatchQueue.Activate();


    }


/// <summary>
    /// true if Nfc is available on the mobile device
    /// otherwise return false
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAvailable {
        get {
            return _session?.Ready ?? false;
        }
    }
```

I've tried some solutions but nothing has worked out for now. Any suggestions?

I tried to change the session using different ones, like the NFCReadingSession, but still no result.